# Is it possible build a huffman algorithm with characters of '0' and '1'?

Tags: python, image, compression, huffman-code

I have an array with this format:

```
P1
5 5
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
```

and I want to compress this array in order using huffman. My question is if it's possible because when I search by huffman algorithm I only find with multiple characters and didn't nothing similar to this.

If so possible, how would I make it?

I've tried this:

```
def getBitString(file):
   file = open(ficheiro, "rb").read()
   string = ""
   for byte in file:
     print(byte)
     string+=format(byte,'08b')

   return string
```

I only converted the file to binary. I'm thinking about the problem to progress but I'm stuck I need some help

Comment: Please share what you tried.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You're already dealing with a tiny amount of binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Huffman encoding uses the probability of characters from an alphabet inside a text to safe space when encoding. For it to work you will need an to have an alphabet with more than two characters. Two characters would need 1 bit to store and 1 bit when encoded. That would not safe anything.

With your example data you could see every row as a characters. But there is an other requirement for the Huffman encoding to be helpful: the characters have to repeat, the more the better. There would be only 5 non-repeating characters.

In your simple case of encoding 25 bits Huffman encoding is not going to be helpful. With a lot more repeating data it might be.

Comment: I saw a real example and there are a lot of rows that repeat so huffman can be a right choise.In the previosly example I can see P 1 and 3 as individually characters and so on each row as a character?

Comment: Then you have to group your bits into characters in a smart way. Try groups of 4 to 8 bits and see what compresses best.

Comment: Also keep in mind that there are easy to use compression algorithms like gzip or bzip that might do the job as well.